# Is there a way to echo on a UNIX terminal the output of a local server running a web-socket?

Tags: debugging, unix, curl, websocket

I am running some code that implements a web-socket server locally.

I'd like to echo the output of it on a Unix Terminal to verify whether it works correctly.

The **curl** command [page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) does not seem to state the support the web-socket protocol.

Are you aware of any other **UNIX** commend that does so?

Comment: Chrome has an extension might be useful in your case [Dark WebSocket Terminal](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-websocket-terminal/dmogdjmcpfaibncngoolgljgocdabhke?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

My tool [websocat](https://github.com/vi/websocat) supports it (and WebSocket server as well).

Other alternatives include multiple tools named "wscat" ([1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat),[2](https://github.com/websockets/wscat),[3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat2)), ["ws"](https://github.com/websockets/ws) and maybe others.